# How should I propose to poop?

Tags: minute-quest

In the third building I come across in my adventure, I stumble in on what appears to be a living turd sitting on a toilet.  The option presented is "PROPOSE", but clicking it doesn't seem to do anything.

[image: screenshot]

What does proposing do and how do I do it?

Comment: Well... this is uhh.... unexpected.

Comment: I absolutely love the title.

Comment: I believe its has something to do with the skills you chose. I chose mainly strength, vitality and luck and i got the grounded skill from proposed. My quess is that he is some sort of assistant and that he tells you what skill suits your character best.

Comment: On second thought it has something to do with the weapons you have equiped. The sword (you have equiped in your screenshot) has the pow10 skill whereas the club has grounded, pow10 and regen2. As far as our brown friend, i still think he's some kind of assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Propose button actually is more of a "Recommend" button in-game. It basically proposes pets that you have that are more likely to synergize with the equipment that you have.

Remember that since certain equipment when worn together can give you special abilities, like Super Mach, Killer, Deathmarch, Paralyze, what Propose does is the game's way of recommending a different pet to add or change a different ability for your loadout.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 141st level and have seen three or four of these buildings by the 4.5 km mark.  I have a big collection of weapons and pets.  Sometimes when I hit propose it cycles through pets.  Sometimes it cycles through weapons.  My answer is, a specific bathroom will cycle through pets telling you their benefits, and others cycle through weapons.

Comment: Does it only suggest items that work together or just any at random?

Comment: I think I need you to clarify ... items don't work together in Minute Quest, unless I've missed something colossal.  You have a particular weapon, and a particular pet "armed" at any one time.  A specific bathroom will cycle through each of your weapons or each of your pets.  Not both.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some kind of combo system.  If I take my setup that gives ACCUP10, CRITUP10, ACCUP10 and change only my pet, it becomes ACCUP10, ACCUP20, MGUARDUP10.  Assumption there would be that new pet gives ACCUP20, MGUARDUP10.  However, if I change my armor, I get ACCUP20, SPDUP 10